# I want to meld and pick the pack .. there is a seven on top of pack I have two sevens and a outside triple .. can I pick pack for seven?

Tags: canasta

Can I pick pack for 7 ? I have 125 points and clean triple . This is my initial held . Or must I have 3 7? This is canasta

Answer (score 1):

You only need 2 natural cards matching the top of the discard pile to pick up the pile; not 3. As long as your meld is enough points to meet the minimum, you can do this.

The 3 sevens are only 15 points, so your other triple would have to be aces in order for the total to reach the minimum 50 points. (if it is 8-K then that’s only 45 points).

> When the discard pile is topped by a wild card or a black three, at least one natural card must be discarded on top of the pile before the pile may be taken. Then, **a player may take that card (and the pile) only with a natural pair of the same rank from their hand**. Before touching the discard pile, the player should show the pair (together with any additional cards if needed to meet the minimum count of an initial meld).

https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/